# WPF need to bind to complex type

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a ViewModel for a window

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
}
```

The viewModel has a base class.  The base class has a complex type as a property that is created when the app starts.

```
public class ViewModelBase {
     public Configuration Config { get; set; }
}
```

In my view, I need to bind to properties on the Config property and get change notifications.  The datacontext of the View is the MainWindowViewModel  and I have a binding statement like

```
Text="{Binding Config.Property}"
```

Any advice on how to accomplish what I'm trying for?

Comment: Not sure that the config property should be on this base class. What concerns/relationship does the ViewMobelBase have with the Configuration object. You may want in your derived class be more specific to what you are trying to display

Comment: The reason it is in the base is because it is also needed in other ViewModels

Comment: Sure... but this "base" class should contain view specific items. Perhaps a ConfigurationViewMobel that you inherit would be better. Just an observation rather than anything to do with your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have there should work fine.  If the Config property is changing then you'll also want to have `ViewModelBase` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise the event when the Config property is changed, similarly if the properties that you're binding to in the Configuration class are changing then that will also need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise the events when its properties change.

Comment: Alternatively you could just use the .net `Settings` class. That inherits from `ApplicationSettingsBase` and automagically implements `INPC`.